# Printing out a list object created by a class

Tags: python, list, class, oop

I am trying to create a program, which generates a list of all the numbers in the range of 0 to any number, in random order and with each number appearing only once (in order to program some sorting algorithms and test them on this list afterwards). I tried to create a List() class, which takes as argument the length of the list it is supposed to create:

```
from random import randint, shuffle

class List():
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def create_list(self):
        list_ = [i for i in range(self.length)]

testlist = List(10)
print(testlist)
```

Now the problem is, instead of a list, the output of this code is just

```
<__main__.List object at 0x02DD1FF0>
```

Is there anybody who can tell me why and how to correct this?
Note that I'm a beginner, I began learning python about 2 weeks ago and this is more or less my first attempt in OOP...

Comment: That *is* correct. You haven't defined a `__repr__`, so you see the default. Also note that: 1. `create_list` never gets called; and 2. when it is called, it won't return anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This helped me a lot, it worked when I defined the return value of create_list() as list_ and actually called that function afterwards, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `__str__()` method of the object. This is what gets called when you print an object that isn't inherently "printable"